# RestSharp to edit one element of xml file

Tags: c#, xml, put, restsharp

For the documentation of the API I am using, the instructions are:

```
To edit an existing resource: GET the full XML file for the resource you want to change (/api/customers/7), edit its content as needed, then PUT the whole XML file back to the same URL again.
```

Now my question is, if I only want to edit one element (out of many) in XML file, is there any function in RestSharp to allow me to only edit that single element, without deserializing the entire XML?

As an example, my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<customer>
    <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
    <id_default_group xlink:href="http://heatherfazelinia.com/api/groups/3"><![CDATA[3]]></id_default_group>
    <id_lang xlink:href="http://heatherfazelinia.com/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[1]]></id_lang>
    <newsletter_date_add><![CDATA[2013-12-13 08:19:15]]></newsletter_date_add>
    <ip_registration_newsletter></ip_registration_newsletter>
    <last_passwd_gen><![CDATA[2014-06-20 16:56:30]]></last_passwd_gen>
    <secure_key><![CDATA[6a9b9eab95448d74a026b869d8cd723e]]></secure_key>
    <deleted><![CDATA[0]]></deleted>
    <passwd><![CDATA[6028853eb1033578f7432015042fa486]]></passwd>
    <lastname><![CDATA[DOE]]></lastname>
    <firstname><![CDATA[John]]></firstname>
    <email><![CDATA[pub@prestashop.com]]></email>
    <id_gender><![CDATA[1]]></id_gender>
    <birthday><![CDATA[1970-01-15]]></birthday>
    <newsletter><![CDATA[1]]></newsletter>
    <optin><![CDATA[1]]></optin>
    <website></website>
    <company></company>
    <siret></siret>
    <ape></ape>
    <outstanding_allow_amount><![CDATA[0.000000]]></outstanding_allow_amount>
    <show_public_prices><![CDATA[0]]></show_public_prices>
    <id_risk><![CDATA[0]]></id_risk>
    <max_payment_days><![CDATA[0]]></max_payment_days>
    <active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
    <note></note>
    <is_guest><![CDATA[0]]></is_guest>
    <id_shop><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop>
    <id_shop_group><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop_group>
    <date_add><![CDATA[2014-08-01 13:20:37]]></date_add>
    <date_upd><![CDATA[2014-08-01 13:20:37]]></date_upd>
<associations>
<groups node_type="group">
    <group xlink:href="http://heatherfazelinia.com/api/groups/3">
    <id><![CDATA[3]]></id>
    </group>
</groups>
</associations>
</customer>
</prestashop>
```

I have figured out how to deserialize specific values, for example: "firstname" and "lastname".

But my current question is specifically: If I wanted to only edit "firstname" of that XML with a PUT request, would I need to deserialize and edit the entire XML? Or is there any function in RestSharp to help with that, where I can directly have it edit only the "firstname" element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RestSharp` isn't an serialization / deserialization framework. Its a *"Simple REST and HTTP API Client for .NET"*. It does come with an out-of-the-box features such as deserializing xml / json into proper objects (using a 3rd party framework like Json.NET).

Therefore, it cant do what you're asking, you'll have to deserialize the whole xml and change the attributes you desire.

What you need to be done can be done quite easily using [`LINQ 2 XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
//Assuming you get your xml as a string:
var xml = XElement.Load(yourXmlString);

var firstName = xml.Element("customer").Element("firstname");
var lastName = xml.Element("customer").Element("lastname");

firstName.Value = "firstChange";
lastName.Value = "secondChange";

var returnedXml = xml.ToString();
```

Of course, you'll have to add nullity checks, exception handling, etc.

Comment: Quick question on that example you gave, it doesn't seem to be work, firstName and lastName are coming up as null with the XML I posted in the example. Were you able to get that code to work? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Found an edit that made it work... 

// XML edit value
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load("response.txt");
            XElement root = document.Root;
            Console.WriteLine(root.Element("customer").Element("firstname").Value);